# Derived types generating their own ForeignKey field in code first using TPH

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity-framework-core, tph

I'm using EF Core and implementing inheritance in a table-per-hierarchy (TPH) approach. I've found that once I added the hierarchy objects to my data model the migration is adding a foreign key for the base table and what appears to be a duplicate that the descendant classes are using.

Relationship is from `Transaction` (parent) to `TransactionItem` (child).

Object hierarchy:

- TransactionItem (Base class)

  - Attachment
  - Check
  - Envelope
  - Stub

Using Fluent API to define the relationship between `Transaction` and `TransactionItem` using the `TransactionItem.TransactionId` field as the foreign key:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionItem>(t =>
{
    t.ToTable("TransactionItem");
    t.HasKey(a => a.Id);
    t.Property(a => a.ConcurrencyStamp)
        .IsRequired()
        .IsConcurrencyToken();
    t.Property(a => a.Created)
        .IsRequired();
    t.HasOne(a => a.Transaction)
        .WithMany(a => a.TransactionItems)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.TransactionId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    t.HasDiscriminator<string>("ItemType")
        .HasValue<Check>("Check")
        .HasValue<Stub>("Stub")
        .HasValue<Envelope>("Envelope")
        .HasValue<Attachment>("Attachment");
});
```

The migration Up method is creating the base class table (TPH) with  `TransactionId` and `TransactionId2` columns, each relating to the same parent table:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
name: "TransactionItem",
columns: table => new
{
    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
    Created = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: false),
    ItemType = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
    PageName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
    Sequence = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
    TransactionId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
    TransactionId2 = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
    CheckType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
    Micr = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
    MicrValid = table.Column<bool>(nullable: true),
    OcrId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
},
constraints: table =>
{
    table.PrimaryKey("PK_TransactionItem", x => x.Id);
    table.ForeignKey(
        name: "FK_TransactionItem_Transaction_TransactionId",
        column: x => x.TransactionId,
        principalTable: "Transaction",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    table.ForeignKey(
        name: "FK_TransactionItem_Transaction_TransactionId2",
        column: x => x.TransactionId2,
        principalTable: "Transaction",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
});
```

When I look at the ModelSnapshot.cs code I see the following relationships specific to the objects in the inheritance model establishing a foreign key for the derived class entities using the `TransactionId2` column.

```
modelBuilder.Entity("SampleProject.Data.DataModels.TransactionItem", b =>
    {
        b.HasOne("SampleProject.Data.DataModels.Transaction", "Transaction")
            .WithMany("TransactionItems")
            .HasForeignKey("TransactionId");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity("SampleProject.Data.DataModels.Attachment", b =>
    {
        b.HasOne("SampleProject.Data.DataModels.Transaction")
            .WithMany("Attachments")
            .HasForeignKey("TransactionId2");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity("SampleProject.Data.DataModels.Check", b =>
    {
        b.HasOne("SampleProject.Data.DataModels.Transaction")
            .WithMany("Checks")
            .HasForeignKey("TransactionId2");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity("SampleProject.Data.DataModels.Envelope", b =>
    {
        b.HasOne("SampleProject.Data.DataModels.Transaction")
            .WithMany("Envelopes")
            .HasForeignKey("TransactionId2");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity("SampleProject.Data.DataModels.Stub", b =>
    {
        b.HasOne("SampleProject.Data.DataModels.Transaction")
            .WithMany("Stubs")
            .HasForeignKey("TransactionId2");
    });
```

I'm obviously missing something but can't figure out what it is. I want to be able to use inheritance hierarchy with TPH approach and a single foreign key field from the base class table (`TransactionItem`) to the parent (`Transaction`). I appreciate any help that you can provide.

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell without having the full model/configuration. For instance, do you have public collection (`IEnumerable<Attachment>`, `ICollection<Attahment>`, `IList<Attachment>` etc.) property `Attachments` in your `Transaction` class?

Comment: Great point. The `Transaction` has a property for `ICollection<TransactionItem>` as well as read-only convenience properties - `List<Check>`, `List<Attachment>`, etc. implemented as: `return this.TransactionItems?.OfType<Check>().ToList();` Maybe those properties are the issue. I'll remove them and see if that changes the results.

Comment: @IvanStoev you're exactly right. I removed those _convenience_ properties and the migration was added correctly. I'll post an answer here for anyone else that ends up in my same predicament. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Ivan Stoev, I created this problem by having the parent object (`Transaction` in this case) implement read-only *convenience* properties for lists of my derived class types.

Because `Transaction` declared properties like below, the ef migration was creating new relationships/foreign keys for them.

```
public List<Check> Checks
{
    get
    {
        return this.TransactionItems?.OfType<Check>().ToList();
    }
}
```

I've since implemented these as methods so as not to conflict with the conventions of ef.

Many thanks to Ivan Stoev for prompting this discovery!